# CS1998 throws an error instead of a warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Working on a new system at a new job with VS Professional 2015 w/Update 3 and `CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously` is throwing an actual build error instead of a warning. On my other systems this is simply a build warning, NOT an error.

Is there a VS option somewhere where I can change this back to being a warning?

Answer (score 5):

See the Warnings as Errors field in the Build tab in Project Properties.

Comment: Damned, beat me to it! Good job @SLaks